# NSNumber with 0 convert to NSInteger/NSUInteger become nil

Tags: ios, nsnumber, nsinteger, nsuinteger

Why NSNumber of 0 cannot be converted to correct NSInteger/NSUInteger value?

```
NSUInteger a = [@0 unsignedIntegerValue]; // a become nil
```

Why is `a` in the above line of code nil. Shouldn't it be equal to `0`?

**In the console:**

```
(lldb) po [@0 intValue]
0

(lldb) po [@0 integerValue]
<nil>

(lldb) po [@0 unsignedIntegerValue]
<nil>
```

---

Update:

```
(lldb) p [@0 unsignedIntegerValue]
(NSUInteger) $0 = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use p not po

```
(lldb) p [@0 integerValue]
(NSInteger) $1 = 0
(lldb) p [@0 intValue]
(int) $2 = 0
(lldb) p [@0 unsignedIntegerValue]
(NSUInteger) $3 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Clear myself, I'm assigning `@0` to a NSUInteger variable, and it turns out to be a `nil`. Is there any advise not to use NSInteger/NSUInteger?

Comment: [@0 integerValue] is not a object. You should use p value instead of po object